# Preferred NuGet packages for undefined classes in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, intellisense

There are some NuGet packages I use quite often. Recent versions of Visual Studio, when encountering an undefined class, offers to automatically install NuGet packages that happen to include a class with that name.

[image]

But not always does it offer the packages I want to use.

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio to offer me the right packages? Or is that out of my control?

Does Microsoft hand-pick the packages offered? Or does it need some change (a tag) in the packages, so that they are included into the offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is out of your control. And the setting is under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Text Editor**-->**C#**-->**Advanced**-->**Suggest usings for types in NuGet packages**

[image]

And **Microsoft** adds this feature recently but it is too fragile and its function is not so powerful enough and cannot do much more things. And it can only suggest the NuGet package which it want and cannot get the one based on your requirements.

**But** [ReSharper Extension](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) has a feature called [NuGet Browser](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/NuGet_Browser.html),  it can search the related NuGet packages under the suggested IntelliSense by namespace or class.

[image]

**Besides**, ReSharper extension is a paid extension and new users has 30 days for free use. If it does not meet your requirements, you have to [suggest a feature on DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion) to raise your wish to **Microsoft**.